# Difference between load of librosa and read of scipy.io.wavfile

Tags: python, scipy, librosa

I have a question about the difference between the `load` function of librosa and the `read` function of `scipy.io.wavfile`.

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
import librosa

fs, data = wavfile.read(name)
data, fs = librosa.load(name)
```

The imported voice file is the same file. If you run the code above, the values ​​of the data come out of the two functions differently. I want to know why the value of the data is different.

Comment: In what do they differ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the docstring of [`librosa.core.load`](http://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.load.html):

> Load an audio file as a floating point time series.
>
> Audio will be automatically resampled to the given rate (default sr=22050).
>
> To preserve the native sampling rate of the file, use sr=None.

[`scipy.io.wavfile.read`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html) does not automatically resample the data, and the samples are not converted to floating point if they are integers in the file.

Comment: Implicit resampling is imao just one of several drawbacks of `librosa`.

Comment: Are they different in terms of how fast they can load a file ?

Comment: And I also discovered that librosa is much slower than scipy when reading the audios files. Maybe it is due to re-sampling?

Answer (score 7):

The data is different because `scipy` does not normalize the input signal.

Here is a snippet showing how to change `scipy` output to match `librosa`'s:

```py
nbits = 16

l_wave, rate = librosa.core.load(path, sr=None)
rate, s_wave = scipy.io.wavfile.read(path)

s_wave /= 2 ** (nbits - 1)

all(s_wave == l_wave)
# True
```

Comment: Got an error (`s_wave_old /= 2 ** (nbits - 1)
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'divide' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int16') with casting rule 'same_kind')` running this unchanged, so had to convert the type `s_wave = np.array(s_wave_orig, dtype=np.float32)`

Answer (score 5):

It's worth also mentioning that `librosa.load()` normalizes the data (so that all the data points are between 1 and -1), whereas `wavfile.read()` does not.

Comment: The data points are actually between 1 and -1, but why scaling and does it make FFT results different?

Answer (score 2):

`librosa.core.load` has support for 24 bit audio files and 96kHz sample rates. Because of this, converting to float and default resampling, it can be considerably slower than `scipy.io.wavfile.read` in many cases.

Comment: For more explanation you can refer to this link:
https://github.com/SeanNaren/deepspeech.pytorch/issues/40